# How to modify multiple CASE statements

Tags: sql-server

It's me again. I would just like to ask your opinion on how shall I modify my SELECT statament query. So basically I created a user defined field called "Force Schedule2", if this checkbox is tick  (equals 1), then even if the item is on schedule 1, it will display on schedule 2. How shall I add it on my existing case statement?

my current SELECT statement is:

```
SELECT
   CASE 
       WHEN 
           WorkOrder.DateCreated < 
           (
             CASE 
                 WHEN 
                    (DATEPART(dw, dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start) = 2) 
                 THEN 
                    (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 3 
                 ELSE 
                    (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 1 
              END
           ) 
       THEN 
           1 
       ELSE 
           2 
   END 

   AS ScheduleTime
```

and my user defined field for "Force Schedule2 is:

```
dbo.AdditionalInfo.UserDefined3 AS ForceSched
```

[image]

Comment: Is that code inside the `WHERE` block? Why not just have your standard condition + `OR UserDefined3 = 1`? Or is this just a `SELECT` issue? It's not clear to me what you are doing exactly. Perhaps if you show a bit more of your query or the tables you are using... Why are you adding 15hs and then subtracting 3 or 1 days?

Comment: Does that checkbox change which rows should be displayed? Or will that simply change what is displayed in a column? It's still unclear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious what you're trying to do here with your date operation. You could do something simple like this:

```
CASE
    WHEN dbo.AdditionalInfo.UserDefined3 = 1
        THEN 2
    WHEN WorkOrder.DateCreated < (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(dw, dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start) = 2) THEN (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 3 ELSE (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 1 END) 
        THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 
END AS ScheduleTime
```

Basically it hits the condition and exits the statement. If you flipped it so your date operation was first it would return 1, so you still need to think about the order you're entering things into case statement.

Comment: great! this works:) Im sorry, I should have stated that it is within my SELECT.

Comment: My comment about the date bit was more so that it wasn't clear why you were doing the operation or what effect it was meant to have. There are a lot more ways this could be solved, and including more information might get you a better performing answer.

Comment: This could be simplified a bit by doing `WHEN dbo.AdditionalInfo.UserDefined3 <> 1 AND WorkOrder.DateCreated < ... THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`. :)